# How to use CEGUI with Ogre in xcode

Tags: ios, macos, ogre, cegui

I have build Ogre and CEGUI successfully,but I don't know how to use cegui with ogre in Xcode.
I am stuck in configuring environment in Xcode and I googled but find no solution...

Is there specific steps or tutorials to do this?
Thanks!